# Python setting Decimal Place range without rounding?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I take a float variable, and control how far out the float goes without round()? For example.

```
w = float(1.678)
```

I want to take x and make the following variables out of it.

```
x = 1.67
y = 1.6
z = 1
```

If I use the respective round methods:

```
x = round(w, 2) # With round I get 1.68 
y = round(y, 1) # With round I get 1.7
z = round(z, 0) # With round I get 2.0
```

It's going to round and alter the numbers to the point where there no use to me. I understand this is the point of round and its working properly. How would I go about getting the information that I need in the x,y,z variables and still be able to use them in other equations in a float format?

Comment: `[math.floor(w * 10 ** i) / 10 ** i for i in range(3)]`

Comment: The above comment is actually what I used in this case. I'm not able to accept it as the answer as it was posted as a comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can do:

```
def truncate(f, n):
    return math.floor(f * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n
```

testing:

```
>>> f=1.923328437452
>>> [truncate(f, n) for n in range(7)]
[1.0, 1.9, 1.92, 1.923, 1.9233, 1.92332, 1.923328]
```

Comment: Thank you! Long-term I feel this is going to be the best bet for my project!

Comment: truncate(-36.963792534813) produces rounded output - 
'-36.9637925349'

Comment: @Vijender for negative numbers you need to use `ceil` instead of `floor`.  Or you could make it work for both cases with `math.trunc`.

Comment: nice answer solves a lot of problems, thanks :)

Comment: @MarkRansom any advantage or issues for using `int()` over `math.trunc()`?

Comment: @27px I believe they're the same, but I'm not 100% sure.  Since it was a `math` function in the answer, I just picked the appropriate replacement function without thinking about it too much.

Answer (score 8):

A super simple solution is to use strings

```
x = float (str (w)[:-1])
y = float (str (w)[:-2])
z = float (str (w)[:-3])
```

Any of the floating point library solutions would require you dodge some rounding, and using floor/powers of 10 to pick out the decimals can get a little hairy by comparison to the above.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to play around with this one. I figured formatting it would create issues as it becomes a string instead of a float?

Comment: I see what you're saying -- Python's floating point arithmetic can sometimes create long strings. But in that case you'd have issues picking out the decimals anyway. A sanity check could instead be iterating from the beginning instead of the end: x = float (str (w)[:4] (etc)

Answer (score 6):

Integers are faster to manipulate than floats/doubles which are faster than strings. In this case, I tried to get time with both approach :

```
  timeit.timeit(stmt = "float(str(math.pi)[:12])", setup = "import math", number = 1000000)
```

~1.1929605630000424

for :

```
timeit.timeit(stmt = "math.floor(math.pi * 10 ** 10) / 10 ** 10", setup = "import math", number = 1000000)
```

~0.3455968870000561

So it's safe to use math.floor rather than string operation on it.

Comment: Worked  with [Avraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2726543/avraham)

Answer (score 3):

If you just need to control the precision in format

```
pi = 3.14159265
format(pi, '.3f') #print 3.142 # 3 precision after the decimal point
format(pi, '.1f') #print 3.1
format(pi, '.10f') #print 3.1415926500, more precision than the original
```

If you need to control the precision in floating point arithmetic

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec=4 #4 precision in total
pi = decimal.Decimal(3.14159265)
pi**2 #print Decimal('9.870') whereas '3.142 squared' would be off
```

--edit--

Without "rounding", thus truncating the number

```
import decimal
from decimal import ROUND_DOWN
decimal.getcontext().prec=4
pi*1 #print Decimal('3.142')

decimal.getcontext().rounding = ROUND_DOWN
pi*1 #print Decimal('3.141')
```

Comment: The format section of your example rounds the numbers when I switch pi to the value in my example. I did learn a ton from this example on other things, but the rounding is what I was trying to stay away from, I needed non rounded numbers.

Comment: @Branzol . You're still rounding, just with a different rule. Sorry I didn't see it clearly  that you're "rounding" 1.67 as 1.6 and then 1.

Comment: Why must you `from decimal import ROUND_DOWN` if you've already `import decimal`?

Comment: Use pi.normalize() instead of pi*1

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest answer is :

```
from math import trunc

w = 1.678
x = trunc(w * 100) / 100
y = trunc(w * 10) / 10
z = trunc(w)
```

Comment: The `trunc()` is equivalent to the `floor()` function for a positive float (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.trunc)), so your answer is actually the same as the accepted answer.

Comment: @AlexK it isn't really the same answer, since `trunc()` works for both positive and negative float, but the accepted answer only works 100% of the time without rounding for positive float. See [this comment under the accepted answer mentioning the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246455/python-setting-decimal-place-range-without-rounding#comment93080988_29257837).

Answer (score 0):

also this:

```py
>>> f = 1.678
>>> n = 2
>>> int(f * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n
1.67
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only math, I believe you can do this:

```
>>> f = 8.225
>>> f - f % 0.01
8.22
```

Using strings you can do something like this:

```
>>> float(str(f)[:4])
8.22
```

Some more examples of the first one just for fun:

```
>>> r = lambda f: f - f % 0.01
>>> r(2.368)
2.36
>>> r(2.36888888)
2.36
>>> r(2.323)
2.32
>>> r(2.326)
2.32
```

Doesn't work with a single decimal, but works with 2 or more:

```
>>> r = lambda f,p: f - f % p
>>> r(2.356366,0.1)
2.3000000000000003
>>> r(2.356366,0.01)
2.35
>>> r(2.356366,0.001)
2.356
>>> r(2.356366,0.0001)
2.3563
>>> r(2.356366,0.00001)
2.35636
```

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/4nj5gu/comment/d44bszf/

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way to get integer:

series_col.round(2).apply(lambda x: float(str(x).split(".",1)[0]))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).