# How to prevent automatic rounding in print function when printing a float number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Let's consider this situation:

```
from math import sqrt

x = sqrt(19) # x : 4.358898943540674

print("{:.4f}".format(x))
# I don't want to get 4.3589
# I want to get 4.3588
```

The `print()` function rounds the number automatically, but I don't want this. What should I do?

Comment: See related [How to round a floating point number up to certain decimal place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518641/how-to-round-a-floating-point-number-up-to-certain-decimal-place) for answers that don't have any "edge" cases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python setting Decimal Place range without rounding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246455/python-setting-decimal-place-range-without-rounding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to round the number *down* to the 4th decimal place rather than round it to the nearest possibility, you could do the rounding yourself.

```
x = int(x * 10**4) / 10**4
print("{:.4f}".format(x))
```

This gives you

```
4.3588
```

Multiplying and later dividing by `10**4` shifts the number 4 decimal places, and the `int` function rounds down to an integer. Combining them all accomplishes what you want. There are some edge cases that will give an unexpected result due to floating point issues, but those will be rare.

Comment: yes it works. but for lengthy data it costs very much. your answer does 4 extra operation in order to catch the precision while I calculated it in my code. so why I calculate it again?

Comment: @Javadmk: If you store the value of `10**4` that will reduce the number of operations. There is a way to do this with string handling, avoiding the multiplication and the division, but that route has some multiple operations and tricky issues of its own and I doubt that it would be significantly faster. My method is short and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. `truncate` function [courtesy of @user648852](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29257837/9209546).

```
from math import sqrt, floor

def truncate(f, n):
    return floor(f * 10 ** n) / 10 ** n

x = sqrt(19) # x : 4.358898943540674

print("{0}".format(truncate(x, 4)))
# 4.3588
```

Comment: as I said in the previous answer, this is not an efficient way for solving the problem. any better algorithm will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do more work initially and cut away a fixed number of excess digits:

```
from math import sqrt

x = sqrt(19) # x : 4.358898943540674

print(("{:.9f}".format(x))[:-5])
```

gives the desired result. This could still fail if x has the form `?.????999996` or similar, but the density of these numbers is rather small.

Comment: 19 is just an example, is must work for all numbers like 1.