# How can I print a number without rounding?(Python)

Tags: python

Edit: I saw the two similar questions but I didn't get my answer.

I want to square some numbers with 4 numbers after the decimal point:

```
import math
lis=math.sqrt(19)
print("%.4f" % lis)
```

`sqrt(19)=4.35889894` so the output will be:

```
4.3589
```

and I want it to be:

```
4.3588
```

without rounding up.
What do I do?

Comment: `print float(str("%0.6f"%math.sqrt(19))[:-2])`

Comment: Because `round` use 2 value (src,dst), if you want escape SRC+2,DEST.

Comment: Strange. This is exactly the same example as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592945/how-to-prevent-automatic-rounding-in-print-function-when-printing-a-float-number

Comment: strange. Why 19??

Comment: i not type as an answer and not read this article! And you try bad!

Comment: @dsgdfg what are you talking about?

Comment: @Georgy  about comments,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `math.floor` to always round down. Wrap the final output in `math.floor` and that will do it.

```
import math
lis=math.sqrt(19)
print(math.floor(lis * 10000)/10000.0)
```

returns 4.3588

Comment: I edited the code a bit to gave you that precision of a float. But `math.floor()` do the trick and is easily understandable.

Comment: Only if you take this too literally and downvote instantly without thinking... See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246455/python-setting-decimal-place-range-without-rounding?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Yeah no offense taken but @HoseinShendabadi this does exactly what you need and it doesn't feel hackerish at all, so not sure why you downvoted it or didn't want to accept it as an answer?

Comment: @onlyphantom I'm sorry pal but the code returned "4" to me

Comment: hmm @HoseinShendabadi Did you see the edited code that I put up 12 mins ago? `print(math.floor(lis * 10000)/10000.0)` returned exactly 4.3588 - which is what you asked for.

Comment: @onlyphantom My bad :) .

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is more of a hack

float(str(math.sqrt(19))[:6])

Let me know if this isn't something that solves your problem

Comment: why `[:-2]` ? your definition isn't global !

Comment: What do you mean by global?

Comment: `float(str(math.sqrt(1900000))[:6])` ?????

Comment: As I said, it's a hack. Also, case specific to the question. That's why I've asked the op to let me know if they need another approach

Comment: It worked with something like 19
But when I input a number like 4 it returns "2.0" but I need "2.0000"