# How do I use string formatting in order to receive a number with exactly 5 number after decimal point?

Tags: python, string, formatting, numbers, decimal

I am trying to get a number with exactly 5 numbers after decimal point, no rounding!
for example:

```
2.34567836576 ----> 2.34567
```

We are allowed to use only string formatting.
I only succeeded to do that with rounding unfortunately.
**Using 3.7 Python**
Thank you!

Comment: `float(str(a)[:7])`--->`2.34567` I don't if this is *Pythonic*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python setting Decimal Place range without rounding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246455/python-setting-decimal-place-range-without-rounding)

Comment: it works! but is it string formatting?

Comment: Nope. I just typecasted your float to string and took a slice of the string i.e until 5 decimal point and converted it back to float.

Comment: Note : You need to change the length of the slice based on your number. The above works only for numbers in range 0 to 9.99999...

Answer (score 0):

Just use string formatting.

```
"{:.5f}".format(232.34567836576)
> '232.34568'
```

Edit: Here's a super hacky way using mostly string formats:

```
("{0:." + str(len("{0:.5f}".format(22.34567836576))) +"}").format("{0:f}".format(22.34567836576))
22.34567
```

I'm not sure what the point of the exercise is. What I'm doing is truncating a string to the length of the (wrongly) rounded, formatted float.

For what I can find, there's no way of plainly formatting it. I'm sorry if this answer is invalid, had I read your rounding thing beforehand, I wouldn't have commented.

Comment: You code outputs `'2.34568'`. But OP wanted `'2.34567'`

Comment: @TomShchori Look at my comment under the question.

Comment: yep, just saw that. I also succeeded to get 34568 at the end but could not succeed without rounding