# Python setting Decimal Place range without rounding using truncate does not work for some numbers

Tags: python-3.x, truncate, algorithmic-trading

I wish to take in a float variable,
e.g.

```
w = float(1.678)
```

and control how far out the float goes without round(), e.g.

```
x = 1.67        
y = 1.6
z = 1
```

Which was already answered in [Python setting Decimal Place range without rounding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29246455/9406988) and it worked well until one day this number 0.00225 popped up and it some how just doesn't work for this specific number

```
In [161]: truncate(0.00225, 5)
Out[161]: 0.00224
```

0.00224 and 0.00226 also gave similar issues.

Here's the output I got while testing from 0.00223 - 0.00227

```
In [159]: truncate(0.00223, 5)
Out[159]: 0.00223

In [160]: truncate(0.00224, 5)
Out[160]: 0.00223

In [161]: truncate(0.00225, 5)
Out[161]: 0.00224

In [162]: truncate(0.00226, 5)
Out[162]: 0.00225

In [163]: truncate(0.00227, 5)
Out[163]: 0.00227
```

Why does this happen for some numbers and how do I fix it?

(I mainly use this for a trading algo which requires inputs to have precise decimals)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a simple problem and it has no simple solution. I would start by studying this article:

https://realpython.com/python-rounding/