# How to format numbers without rounding in Python?

Tags: python, numbers, number-formatting

I was searching online but could find if this is posible. I have a number, let say `1234.5963657` and I know that with f-string I can do this `f"{number:,.2f}"` to obtain `1,234.60`.

The thing is that the number has been rounded, and I don't want that, I would like to obtain: `1,234.59`. My question is if there's a way to do this as simple as the f-string.

If not, I would have to truncate it or do something like this:

```
number = 1234.5963657
int_part, dec_part = str(number).split('.')
new_number = f"{int_part}.{dec_part[:2]}" # 1234.59
```

Hope my question is clear. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python setting Decimal Place range without rounding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29246455/python-setting-decimal-place-range-without-rounding)

Comment: I read it before creating this post, but I find my way with strings "quicker"

Comment: I believe the word you are looking for is "truncate"

Comment: Yes, I would like to truncate the number, but not like the math.trunc() function which only returns the integer part of the number, because I need also 2 decimals.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truncate to three decimals in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595973/truncate-to-three-decimals-in-python)

Comment: I just check it, I thought it could work, but the same round up happens, I will have to do like the solution I marked, like this:  ('%.3f'%number)[:-1]. With that it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more digit of precision then use a slice to exclude the unwanted digit.

```
f"{number:,.3f}"[:-1]
```

Comment: Ohhh, nice, I think this could be the best  way of doing it, let me try it